# How various Link Time Optimization settings in VC++ work with each other?

Tags: c++, msbuild, linker-errors, visual-studio-2022

I recently faced **error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code -1073741819** building a VC2017 project with VC2022 and after no luck with Google I tried to resolve it myself. It seems the problem is related to "contradicting" or "missing" compiler and linker optimization options, which rises my question.

***There are the following 3 options in C++ Property Pages that can give this error when you provide contradicting or missing values:***

- Configuration Properties

  - **Advanced: Whole Program Optimization** (several options)

    - No Whole Porgram Optimization
    - Use Link Time Code Generation
    - Profile Guided Optimization - Instrument / Optimize / Update
    - inherit from parent or project defaults
- C/C++

  - **Optimization: Whole Program Optimization** (No or /GL)
- Linker

  - **Link Time Code Generation: (several options)**

    - Default
    - Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG:incremental)
    - Use Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)
    - Profile Guided Optimization - Instrument / Optimize / Update
    - inherit from parent or project defaults

In my case I had linker option **/INCREMENTAL**, I was missing linker option **/LTCG:incremental** (it was empty), but had **Advanced: Whole Program Optimization** set to Use Link Time Code Generation. In MSVC2017 it was sufficient but in VC2022 it caused error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code -1073741819.

So, how various Link Time Optimization settings in VC++ work with each other? What is their relationship and defaulting logic?

Comment: `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` in hex, which is an access violation (in Windows). So, this seems like a bug in the linker.

Comment: /INCREMENTAL only makes sense in the Debug configuration.  /LTCG only makes sense in the Release configuration.  So that's a very basic way to avoid conflict and stumble into linker bugs that nobody else puts to the test.

Comment: Thank you Hans, we build Math Simulatiors and we need optimizations enabled even during debugging, that is why we take advantage of  /LTCG:incremental and it is indeed painfull.

Comment: Slightly offtop, but if you need faster debug builds, define `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`